# Frame coordinates of a Plot for background filling

Tags: plotting, frame, background

I want to fill the frame background of a `Plot` with a color for which I am using a `Rectangle` as a `Prolog` item.

```
p1 = Plot[{Sin[2 x], Sin[x]}
  , {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
  , Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}
  , FrameTicks -> Automatic
  , Prolog -> {
    Nest[Lighter, Brown, 5]
    , Rectangle[{0, -1.0}, {2 \[Pi], 1.0}]
    }
  ]
```

[image]

---

Using `AbsoluteOptions` gives the same values that have been used in the `Prolog` section above, but it leaves a small margin.

```
AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange] & @p1
```

> {PlotRange -> {{0., 6.28319}, {-1., 1.}}}

---

**EDIT-1**

I know `PlotRangePadding->None` would get me there, but I want to find the coordinates of the frame box.

---

**Question(s)**

1. How do I determine the frame bounding box coordinates inside the `Prolog` section so that I can put a `Rectangle` there to fill the frame with a specified color.
2. Are there built-in options (or other available solutions) for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: ``AbsoluteOptions`` has been heavily upgraded and improved in V13. If you evaluate ``AbsoluteOptions[p1, PlotRangePadding]`` in V12, you get measurements in the form of ``Scaled[]``. In V13, however, you get ``PlotRangePadding -> {{0.1309, 0.1309}, {0.111111, 0.111111}}``. You can subtract this from coordinates (and add to size of the rectangle) and you will be able to fill the whole area. To do this, I would first plot and use ``Epilog -> a``, then get the ``AbsoluteOptions`` and replace ``p1 /. a -> {Nest ...}``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Scaled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) and avoid the need for explicit coordinates:

```
Plot[{Sin[2 x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> {Nest[Lighter, Brown, 5], 
   Rectangle[Scaled[{-1, 1}], Scaled[{1, -1}]]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** In case you need the plot range for other purposes, you can use undocumented function `` Charting`get2DPlotRange ``:

```
 Plot[{Sin[2 x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
  DisplayFunction ->
     (Show[#, 
       Prolog -> {Nest[Lighter, Brown, 5], 
           Rectangle @@ Transpose[Charting`get2DPlotRange @ #]}] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd expect that you should be able to use `Rectangle[Scaled[{-1, 1}], Scaled[{1, -1}]]` regardless of the version.

Comment: Thank you @Brett. I somehow got some warning message containing `".. Absolute..."` first time I used `Rectangle[Scaled[{-1, 1}], Scaled[{1, -1}]]` in version 13.0 (on Wolfram Cloud) and the message went away when I switched to `Rectangle[Scaled[{-1, 1},{0,0}], Scaled[{1, -1},{0,0}]]`. (The message was probably triggered by some other option as I cannot reproduce it now).

Comment: `Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]` also fills the frame: Can you please explain the `-1`s in the `Scaled` as docs mention ```"... coordinates scaled to run from 0 to 1 across the whole plot range in each direction"```. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, `{0,0}` and `{1,1}` are what I would normally use here.

Comment: @Syed, as Brett commented, `Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]` is the better alternative here. (Although they also work, the alternative forms `Rectangle[Scaled[{-1,1}], Scaled[{1, -1}]`, `Rectangle[Scaled[{-1,-1}], Scaled[{1, 1}]` etc are based on my having used to the two-argument form of `Scaled`)